# onchange and Select not working

Tags: javascript, html, function, select, onchange

Im trying to have the function run but im not sure how to get it to run. i tried on click and creating seperate functions for each select.all i want the function to do is when i choose the option to change the value of a paragraph to the options below. please help.

```
<select id="Providers"  onchange="ProviderChanger()">
    <option value="Empty" id="Empty" name="Empty">Please Select     Provider</option> 
    <option value="Du1" id="Du1" name="Du1">Du 052</option>
    <option value="Du2" id="Du2" name="Du2">Du 055</option>
    <option value="Etisilat1" name="Etisilat1" id="Etisilat1">Etisilat 050</option>
    <option value="Etisilat2" name="Etisilat2" id="Etisilat2">Etisilat 056</option>
    <option value="Office" name="Office" id="Office">House/Office 04</option>
</select>
```

```js
function ProviderChanger()
{
  var ProviderValue = document.getElementById("Provider").value;
  alert(ProviderValue);
  if (ProviderValue == "Du1")
    document.getElementById("Provider").innerHTML = "+971-55";
  else if (ProviderValue == "Du2")
    document.getElementById("Provider").innerHTML = "+971-52";
  else if (ProviderValue == "Etisilat1")
    document.getElementById("Provider").innerHTML = "+971-50";
  else if (ProviderValue == "Etisilat2")
    document.getElementById("Provider").innerHTML = "+971-56";
  else if (ProviderValue == "Office")
    document.getElementById("Provider").innerHTML = "+971-04";
  else
    document.getElementById("Provider").innerHTML = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't this:

```
var ProviderValue = document.getElementById("Provider").value;
```

Be this:

```
var ProviderValue = document.getElementById("Providers").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the script tags around your function?
You miss an s on the end of your Id.

> document.getElementById("Provider")

Comment: Yes i just forgot to include it above